# VIM: swap json values within double quotes

Tags: json, regex, vim

I need to swap tag and value in a json file on multiple lines using VIM editor.

ex: 
this:

`{"value":"PAE","tag":"project:aerospace;id:3364"}
{"value":"#cybersecurity","tag":"project:aerospace;id:3178"}
{"value":"Boeing","tag":"project:aerospace;id:3342"}
{"value":"Airbus","tag":"project:aerospace;id:3335"}`

needs to be:

`{"tag":"project:aerospace;id:3364","value":"PAE"}
{"tag":"project:aerospace;id:3178","value":"#cybersecurity"}
{"tag":"project:aerospace;id:3342","value":"Boeing"}
{"tag":"project:aerospace;id:3335","value":"Airbus"}`

I have gotten as far as `:%s/tag/value/g` (using a temp) for the tag and value, but I need to know how to swap either everything within the 2nd and 4th double quotes or everything before and after the comma.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
%norm! f,xdT{f}i,^R"
```

In above cmd, `^R` you press `ctrl-v ctrl-r`

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

```
:%s/{\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\)}/{\2,\1}/
```

Something like that?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
%s/\v("value":"[^"]+"),("tag":"[^"]+")/\2,\1/
```

Uses "very magic" to make things easier, saves the two groups and replaces them using back-references.

Answer (score 0):

The following regex works for me:

`%s/{("value":".*?"),("tag":".*?")}/{\2,\1}/g`

See it working here: https://regex101.com/r/xR7lR0/1